# reverse printing on python 3.x function

Tags: python, printing, sys

```
import time
def close_garage_dors():
        a= '_ _ _'
        for i in range(5):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(a)

        return 'Doors are closed'
```

Now my question is: How to open this doors :) Basically how to reverse this function, how to delete 5 lines of _ _ _ ? Any ideas?

Comment: If you print these lines in a console there must have a string to open them; you cannot go change your console lines once printed. If this code really closes garages doors, there must have a documentation explaining how to open them. How would you open them without a script?

Comment: a.p. don't worry about the script, i am just curious, how to print 5 lines and then delete each of the line for one second... is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use VT100 tools:

```
CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A' # Cursor up one line
ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K' # Erase current line
print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE)
```

or ANSI escape sequence:

```
CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\033[F' # Cursor up one line
ERASE_LINE = '\033[K' # Clear to the end of line (not erase)
```

Tested and working:

```
import time
CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A' # <--Replace with '\033[F' if you don't have VT100
ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K' # <--Replace with '\033[K' if you don't have VT100
def close_garage_dors():
    a = '_ _ _'
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(.5)
        print(a)
    for b in range(5):
        time.sleep(.5)
        print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE + CURSOR_UP_ONE)
close_garage_dors()
```

Depending on your console you may need to use the ANSI code instead of VT100 tools.

Comment: If you're using windows there are other requirements to make VT100/ANSI work in console. This should work in Linux/iOS consoles though.

Comment: It didn't run in OS X terminal, but I'm not sure why yet. I ran it in qtConsole and it ran, but didn't erase the lines.

Comment: If you're running on iOS device you'll want to use the ANSI codes. I believe there isn't an "Erase Line" command for iOS console (which is probably where it's getting lost). You'll want to use the "Clear to end of line" command, and even then it may require a plugin for qtConsole to display right.

Comment: As I said, I'm running on a Mac using Terminal. I'll assume your code works, but you might want to note in the answer if it requires VT100 emulation.

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test on, but I thought iOS console had VT100. It most definitely should have ANSI at least. Updated answer to reflect tool dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139312/discussion-between-z-bagley-and-eric-shain).

Comment: It now works for me. I originally had an issue with cut and paste into MacOS terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Once you print a newline, you can't delete it. So it is not possible to print over the previous 5 lines with blank lines, for instance.

Instead, you may try to print a very large number (i.e. the height of the screen in lines) of blank lines in order to present a new empty screen.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to overwrite your console output you have to replace *print* function with:

```
print(a),
```

That *comma* tell the interpreter to write on console stdout and don't print a new line, otherwise you can use sys.stdout.write:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(a)
sys.stdout.write('\r')
```